# Random occurrence with preflight response missing allow headers

Tags: reactjs, express, cors, google-cloud-functions, apollo-server

I've got quite random occurrence with this common error:

```
OPTIONS https://api.cloudfunctions.net/api/graphql 404
Access to fetch at 'https://api.cloudfunctions.net/api/graphql' from origin 'https://website.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

What I have is a graphql endpoint with apollo server deployed on Google Cloud Functions and a react client. At some points the client will throw the error on browser but if I try refresh or send the request again 2 or 3 times later it will work.

The preflight request headers being sent:

```
:authority: api.cloudfunctions.net
:method: OPTIONS
:path: /api/graphql
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,id;q=0.8,ms;q=0.7
access-control-request-headers: content-type
access-control-request-method: POST
origin: https://website.com
referer: https://website.com/
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36
```

Expected response

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: content-type
access-control-allow-methods: POST,OPTIONS
access-control-allow-origin: https://website.com
alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43",h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000
content-length: 0
content-type: text/html
date: Wed, 08 Jan 2020 00:38:16 GMT
function-execution-id: 84et92k6mvd9
server: Google Frontend
status: 200
vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers
x-cloud-trace-context: 95d25375171148a66bc629cc41a79d05
x-powered-by: Express
```

Random failed response

```
alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43",h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000
cache-control: private
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 140
content-security-policy: default-src 'none'
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
date: Wed, 08 Jan 2020 00:38:05 GMT
function-execution-id: 84etgky3im1k
server: Google Frontend
status: 404
x-cloud-trace-context: 77040d2c72304cad0d645480b6814f7f;o=1
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-powered-by: Express
```

Looking at the failed response above kinda make sense that it's missing the `access-control-allow-*` headers compared to success one, but again I am not sure how that happened.

Here's my cors config:

```
const corsConfig = {
  origin: ['https://website.com', 'http://localhost:3000'],
  methods: ['POST', 'OPTIONS'],
  credentials: true,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
}

const app = express()
app
  .use(cors(corsConfig))
  .use(...)

...

apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app, cors: corsConfig })
```

Based on few suggestions around I have tried different setup but still sometimes the error happens:

- set `cors: false` in applyMiddleware
- remove cors
- repeat cors as shown above
- add `app.options('*', cors())` as per [doc says](https://github.com/expressjs/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight)

All and all it happens like 1 in 10, sometimes on first request after the user open the site the other times after the user browsing around the site for a while.

Comment: Do you have any middleware or request handlers before `app
  .use(cors(corsConfig))`?

Comment: No, except when I did `app.options('*', cors())` I add that right before it.

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be other middleware that messes up your `cors` settings.

You can try use a different path for your `graphql` endpoint, and apply `cors` only to that path.

```
apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app, path: '/graphql', cors: corsConfig });
```

Alternatively, you can try the express [cors](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) middleware and disable the cors from apollo server

Comment: I have pretty much done all this: path is defaulted to `/graphql` and using express cors as shown above and disable apollo cors by setting it to false. It does seem other middleware might cause the issue but I can't tell what is it and why it doesn't always happen

Comment: @spondbob Did you try running your server outside of Google Cloud for testing, see if this was caused by Google Cloud.

Comment: Haven't really tried that but it works fine on local machine never encounter the issue. I was wondering as well if the Google Frontend server that sit between my client and graphql point doing other things but can't see how that happen.

Answer (score 0):

I used the `apollo-server-cloud-functions` package to solve this problem. Just follow the instructions here (https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/tree/master/packages/apollo-server-cloud-functions) but instead of using `exports.handler = server.createHandler()` swap it out for your own function, like this:

```
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(
  server.createHandler({
    cors: {
      origin: true,
      credentials: true
    }
  })
);
```

That solved it for me!